# lucene collation

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, collation, icu

we are using lucene on .net, and we need a way to implement a search which is "collation agnostic" I do not know if this is the right term but what we need is if I have a user called
[Žuf] I want to be able to find him by etering [zuf] and also in other direction if the user name is [zuf] and I enter [Žuf] I still wanted to find him,  there is always a manual way of striping all characters and crating index on this, but I would prefer soemthing smarter

any ides on this?

thanks
almir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ASCIIFoldingFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ASCIIFoldingFilter.html), combined with a [LowerCaseFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/LowerCaseFilter.html) it should do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Lucene for Java contains a filter that do the job : ICUFoldingFilter (http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/icu/ICUFoldingFilter.html), in the maven package lucene-icu (at least in version 3.6.1).
I don't know if such a library does exist for Lucene.net, but, as it is based on ICU, you should be able to rewrite the code in .NET.

What ICUFoldingFilter is :

> A TokenFilter that applies search term folding to Unicode text, applying foldings from UTR#30 Character Foldings.
>
> This filter applies the following foldings from the report to unicode text:
>
> ```
> - Accent removal
> - Case folding
> - Canonical duplicates folding
> - Dashes folding
> - Diacritic removal (including stroke, hook, descender)
> - Greek letterforms folding
> - Han Radical folding
> - Hebrew Alternates folding
> - Jamo folding
> - Letterforms folding
> - Math symbol folding
> - Multigraph Expansions: All
> - Native digit folding
> - No-break folding
> - Overline folding
> - Positional forms folding
> - Small forms folding
> - Space folding
> - Spacing Accents folding
> - Subscript folding
> - Superscript folding
> - Suzhou Numeral folding
> - Symbol folding
> - Underline folding
> - Vertical forms folding
> - Width folding
> ```
>
> Additionally, Default Ignorables are removed, and text is normalized to NFKC. All foldings, case folding, and normalization mappings are applied recursively to ensure a fully folded and normalized result.